# pattern password javascript

Tags: javascript, regex, passwords

I'm working on a pattern for a password with the following requirements:

1. Min character = 6
2. Max character = 64
3. Min 1 lowercase character
4. Min 1 uppercase character
5. Min 1 number
6. Min 1 special characters

I am using this regex:

```
var passReg = /^(?=^[ -~]{6,64}$)(?=.*([a-z][A-Z]))(?=.*[0-9])(.*[ -/|:-@|\[-`|{-~]).+$/;
```

However, it does not work as expected.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You must be looking for this regex:

```
^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[ -/:-@\[-`{-~]).{6,64}$
```

See [demo](https://regex101.com/r/cS0gC5/1)

Here is explanation:

- `^` - Beginning of string
- `(?=.*[a-z])` - A positive look-ahead to require a lowercase letter
- `(?=.*[A-Z])` - A positive look-ahead to require an uppercase letter
- `(?=.*[0-9])` - A positive look-ahead to require a digit
- `(?=.*[ -/:-@\[-`{-~])` - A positive look-ahead to require a special character
- `.{6,64}` - Any character (but a newline), 6 to 64 occurrences
- `$` - End of string.

Comment: When I use this as the `pattern` value on an `<input type="password" ...` field, it doesn't successfully validate. Entering an invalid password, such as "123123", and then calling `checkValidity()` on the element returns `true` and no hover error appears. Changing to the regex from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76363022/3761310) does correctly validate. Not sure what the difference is or why HTML validation fails for this version.

Comment: @DukeSilver See [Why is my regex valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/76287241/3832970). You need to escape new special chars, i.e. ``pattern="^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[ \-\/:-@\[-`\{-~]).{6,64}$"``

Comment: I had a feeling it was something like that. I had escaped the backslash but I didn't realize I needed to escape other characters too. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Are consider special non-whitespace characters. I think this is complite list:

> ! "   #   $   %   &   '   (   )   *   +   ,   -   .   /   :
>   ; <   =   >   ?   @   [   \   ]   ^   _   `   {   |   }   ~

Try this one:

```
var passReg = /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[!"#$%&'()*+,-.\/:;<=>?\\@[\]^_`{|}~]).{6,64}$/;
```

Look at back reference for special characters. In character sets chars like \ and ] must be escaped.

Answer (score 0):

Input Password and Submit [8 to 25 characters which contain at least one lowercase letter, one uppercase letter, one numeric digit, and one special character]

```
 /^(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[^a-zA-Z0-9])(?!.*\s).{8,25}$/;
```