# Why is my regex valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag and does not work in HTML pattern attribute?

Tags: javascript, html, regex, html-input, ecmascript-next

I am getting the below console warning for this regex pattern:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$
```

> Pattern attribute value `^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$` is valid with the RegExp `u` flag, but not with the `v` flag:
> Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: `/^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/v:` Invalid character in character class.

I cannot see how to create a valid regex pattern for this warning. Please, could somebody explain the error and how to resolve it?

I tried looking at documentation, but could not see how to make it valid for the `v` flag

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The issue is that the [newly introduced `v` flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag) inside HTML `pattern` attribute is **used automatically when compiling a RegExp object**

The value provided to a `pattern` attribute is converted into a regular expression with the [`v` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#flags) for [unicode sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicodeSets).

The [`<input>` *`pattern`* attribute reference states](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern):

> The **compiled pattern regular expression** of an [input](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-input-element) element, if it exists, is a JavaScript [`RegExp`](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexp-regular-expression-objects) object. It is determined as follows:
>
> 1. If the element does not have a [`pattern`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern) attribute specified, then return nothing. The element has no [compiled pattern regular expression](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#compiled-pattern-regular-expression).
> 2. Let *pattern* be the value of the [`pattern`](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern) attribute of the element.
> 3. Let *regexpCompletion* be [RegExpCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexpcreate)(*pattern*, "v").
> 4. If *regexpCompletion* is an [abrupt completion](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-completion-record-specification-type), then return nothing. The element has no [compiled pattern regular expression](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#compiled-pattern-regular-expression).
>    Note: *User agents are encouraged to log this error in a developer console, to aid debugging.*
> 5. Let *anchoredPattern* be the string "`^(?:`", followed by *pattern*, followed by "`)$`".
> 6. Return ! [RegExpCreate](https://tc39.es/ecma262/#sec-regexpcreate)(*anchoredPattern*, "v").

The `/v` flag applies even more restrictions to escaping rules. Since [it allows character class subtraction and intersection](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-v-flag#summary), the *literal* `-` at the end of a character class cannot be left unescaped.

So, if you use the `u` flag, there is no such a restriction, with the `v` flag, it is in place. Cf.

```js
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/u.test("myname@somesite.com"))
console.log(/^[a-zA-Z0-9+_.\-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9]+\.[a-zA-Z0-9]+$/v.test("myname@somesite.com"))
```

So, **always escape literal hyphens inside character classes** in ECMAScript patterns.

Here are more details on which patterns are now considered invalid:

> **Some previously valid patterns are now errors**, specifically those with a character class including either an unescaped [special character](https://arai-a.github.io/ecma262-compare/snapshot.html?pr=2418#prod-ClassSetSyntaxCharacter) `(` `)` `[` `{` `}` `/` `-` `|` (note: `\` and `]` also require escaping inside a character class, but this is already true with the u flag) or [a double punctuator](https://arai-a.github.io/ecma262-compare/snapshot.html?pr=2418#prod-ClassSetReservedDoublePunctuator):
>
> ```
> [(]
> [)]
> [[]
> [{]
> [}]
> [/]
> [-]
> [|]
> [&&]
> [!!]
> [##]
> [$$]
> [%%]
> [**]
> [++]
> [,,]
> [..]
> [::]
> [;;]
> [<<]
> [==]
> [>>]
> [??]
> [@@]
> [``]
> [~~]
> [^^^]
> [_^^]
> ```

Comment: Good to know. This subsection in the link you've given specifically talks about the issue at hand: [How is the v flag different from the u flag?](https://github.com/tc39/proposal-regexp-v-flag#how-is-the-v-flag-different-from-the-u-flag).

Comment: @oriberu I added these pertinent details to the question, that will be surely helpful.

Comment: This answer could benefit by explaining why the console/parser is warning OP about a flag that they did not explicitly include in their regex pattern. Especially since that's not what they asked about, and you changed the title to be about those flags. Otherwise the title likely needs to be reverted.