# HTML input pattern attribute won't validate some regex expression

Tags: html, regex, validation

I have an an email type input which has an email validation pattern attribute set up that doesn't seem to trigger as expected.

```
<form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="enter your email" pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._+\-\']+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$" required>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

It's kind of weird cause part of it works. The regex exp is supposed to be matched only after some text and a dot and some text again is added after the `@` sign. But is also matched instead with no dot and characters after a `someText@sometext` pattern. I've tested it on some online tools like regextester and works fine.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Regex Email validation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5342375/regex-email-validation)

Comment: The pattern works normal when used in javascript.

Comment: It doesn't appear to be using the _pattern_ you're specifying, just the default one.  _[MDN – <input type="email"> – pattern](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#pattern)_.  Additionally, _[MDN – <input type="email"> – pattern validation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#pattern_validation)_.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the docs:

> If the specified pattern is not specified or is invalid, no regular expression is applied and this attribute is ignored completely.
>
> [`<input type="email">` | MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/email#validation)

The specified pattern is compiled with [the `u` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode) ([`v` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicodeSets) for Chrome 112+), which prevents meaningless escapes. Yours has one: `\'`; simply remove the backslash to make the pattern valid. See also [*Valid with the RegExp `u` flag, but not with the `v` flag*](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76285652).

Also, the last `$` is not necessary since [HTML adds it by default](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#the-pattern-attribute), as with `^`.

Try it:

```css
input:invalid {
  outline: 1px solid red;
}
```

```html
<form>
  <input
    type="email"
    placeholder="enter your email"
    pattern="[A-Za-z0-9._+\-']+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}"
    value="someText@sometext"
    required
  >
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Answer (score 3):

Interesting question, as there are not many similar reports.

Here is the console log from *DevTools*.

```
12:13:04.218 example.html:1 Pattern attribute value [A-Za-z0-9._+\-\']+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /[A-Za-z0-9._+\-\']+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$/v: Invalid escape
```

*[MDN – Regular Expressions – Character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Character_class)*.

> *"... In addition to `]` and `\`, the following characters must be escaped in character classes if they represent literal characters: `(`, `)`, `[`, `{`, `}`, `/`, `-`, `|`. This list is somewhat similar to the list of syntax characters, except that `^`, `$`, `*`, `+`, and `?` are not reserved inside character classes ..."*

So, escaping is not required for the apostrophe, `'`.

```
[A-Za-z0-9._+\-']+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$
```

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same issue after escaping the character mentioned above helped me but the browser was converting these slashes and was not rendering correctly when trying to give the value in a string.

What I did was first convert it to regex by adding /regex/ slashes and then converting it into a string and then removing the slash from the start and end.

```
removeFirstAndLastCharacter(pattern.toString())
```

Answer (score -1):

try this:
add ^ before the pattern

```
<form>
  <input type="email" placeholder="enter your email" pattern="^[A-Za-z0- 9._+\-']+@[A-Za-z0-9.\-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,}$" required>
  <button>submit</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Same thing. btw, I didn't add it cause I read in a post the pattern adds it implicitely.