# How to fix a HTML input element pattern attribute not working with name validation regex?

Tags: html, regex, forms, validation

I am trying to use a specific regex to validate a user's first name
on an HTML form.

I tested the regex with a [regex tester](https://regex101.com/r/30IKGO/1), but the regex is not working here as a string in the *pattern* attribute.

What is the issue? Is there a possible solution?

```html
<input
  name="firstName"
  pattern="^[\w'\-,.][^0-9_!¡?÷?¿\/\\+=@#$%ˆ&*(){}|~<>;:[\]]{2,}$"
  title="Your first name must be valid"
  type="text"
  placeholder="First Name"
  required
/>
```

About the rules, it's basically to only allow names.
I'm not sure of all the rules, but it's words only, spaces are
allowed, numbers are not allowed, and only certain characters are
allowed, such as apostrophe (`'`), hyphens (`-`), etc.

Comment: What are the validation rules? It's unclear to me what the expected behavior is.

Comment: @Kosh It's basically to only allow names. I'm not sure of all the rules, but it's words only, spaces are allowed, numbers are not allowed, and only certain characters are allowed, such as apostrophe ('), dashes (-), etc.

Comment: FYI you don't need `^` and `$` when using `pattern`. The pattern is automatically anchored.

Comment: @Brendan, looks like your problem is that you don't know what you want exactly. Try to figure it out first please.

Comment: Read about character classes, https://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html. That should be what you need.

Comment: Try switching the flavor to ECMAScript and turning the `v` flag on. You should then see where the problem is.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285652/valid-with-the-regexp-u-flag-but-not-with-the-v-flag)

Comment: Not a fix but note that the [<input>](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/dev/embedded-content.html#the-input-element) tag does not use and does not need a closing slash and never has in any HTML specification

Comment: @Rob: I don't think it's important, especially because [void elements](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/syntax.html#void-elements), including `<input>`, are allowed to be self-closed with `/>`, just like a `<br>` or `<br />` tag depending on the [doctype](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_doctype.asp). I think it will only be invalid with HTML 4.01. Now that we are often using HTML 5, it won't be a problem. It can just be some sugar for readability, make it more compatible with XML parsers, and perhaps also help some old color highlighting tools work better. But yes, `<div />` is bad!

Comment: @Brendan : I think the problem is due to the chars `|`, `{`, etc in your negative character class. *JavaScript* regex flavor seems to change and now they have to be escaped even in a character class. This is due to [new features with the **v** pattern flag](https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag). See my answer for another kind of pattern.

Comment: @PatrickJanser It's only allowed for backwards compatibility but the fact remains that it is still unspecified for use. The slash does nothing, [it has no meaning](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-in-void-element-start-tags-do-not-mark-the-start-tags-as-self-closing), and browsers are instructed to ignore it so it is pointless. If anything, [it causes harm](https://github.com/validator/validator/wiki/Markup-%C2%BB-Void-elements#trailing-slashes-directly-preceded-by-unquoted-attribute-values) and the W3C validator flags it.

Comment: @PatrickJanser And, as always it's best to follow the standard. Consider compatibility with XML opens a totally different can of worms that almost HTML would not work with.

Comment: @Rob: ok, I hear your point of view. I personally don't think that many people put URLs in `<img alt="Big cat" src=/path/big-cat.jpg/>` without quotes and without a space between the value and the closing slash, but yes, let's stop using them.

Comment: @PatrickJanser It's not a point of view. It's the point blank standard specification.

Comment: @Rob: Ok, fine. I'll update my old bad habits and try to set all the good settings in the IDEs I use. I just did a test with the W3C HTML validator, and it validates, but prints an "info" in green, saying that there's no need to self-close a void element. Just to notice, it's not considered to be an error neither a warning.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue can be due to the characters you declared in the
character classes. According to some changes to the regex flavor
in *JavaScript*, the **u** or **v** flag may be enabled (it seems
to be hard-coded or automatically triggered and cannot be set
manually) and this can cause problems in character classes. For
example, `[a-z|]` has `|` which should now be escaped with `\|` also
in a character class. You're using some in your pattern.

I would not use `\w` but replace it by `\p{L}` which is used to match
any letter in any language. This will match "é" or "ÿ" and not only
English letters without accents.

It's rather complicated to match all the correct cases, but this is
what I can suggest:

```
^(?:\p{L}['´ \-]?)+(?<=[^\s\-'´])$
```

The idea is to accept an input starting with a letter and then
followed by an optional space, hyphen or `'` or `´`, one or multiple
times. To avoid finishing with a space or one of those chars, you
can add a positive lookbehind just before the end of the pattern.

This will avoid accepting something like `Jack-` or `Ooooh'`.

The other advantage is that you can't accept `Jean--Jaques` or
`O''Neil`.

```css
form {
  margin: 1em;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1em;
}

input {
  padding: 0.25em .5em;
  border: 1px solid gray;
}

input[type="text"] {
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 4px inset rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}
input[type="text"]:focus {
  outline: 1px solid gray;
}

input[pattern]:focus:valid {
  border-color: green;
}

input[pattern]:focus:invalid {
  border-color: red;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  background-color: silver;
}

:focus-visible {
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<form action="#">
  <div class="form-element">
    <input
      name="firstName"
      pattern="^(?:\p{L}['´ \-]?)+(?<=[^\s\-'´])$"
      title="Your first name must be valid"
      type="text"
      placeholder="First Name"
      required
    />
  </div>
  <div class="form-element form-submit">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit" />
  </div>
</form>
```

You can also test the regex with examples and the explanation
here: https://regex101.com/r/tmEsgX/2