# Error - Pattern attribute value is not a valid regular expression

Tags: html, regex, react-bootstrap

I am getting error

```
Pattern attribute value [a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])? 
   is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: 
Invalid regular expression: /[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?/v: 
Invalid character in character class
```

for `FormControl`

```
<Form.Control 
    name="email" 
    onChange={updateInput} 
    type="email" 
    pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" 
    placeholder="Email" 
    aria-label="aria-email" 
    isInvalid = {formValidState.email === '' ? false : !formValidState.email } isValid={formValidState.email === '' ? false : formValidState.email } 
    required />
```

This question has been answered in few places but I can't figure out still what is the issue with the above regular expression. What characters am I not correctly escaping or not escaping? Or is it something else?

Comment: why are you using a regex if React bootstrap provides a type property ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285652/valid-with-the-regexp-u-flag-but-not-with-the-v-flag)

Answer (score -2):

The two slashes need to be escaped, you can use backslashes.

```
<Form.Control name="email" onChange={updateInput} type="email" pattern="[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+(?:\.[a-z0-9!#$%&'*+\/=?^_`{|}~-]+)*@(?:[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?\.)+[a-z0-9](?:[a-z0-9-]*[a-z0-9])?" placeholder="Email" aria-label="aria-email" isInvalid = {formValidState.email === '' ? false : !formValidState.email } isValid={formValidState.email === '' ? false : formValidState.email } required />
```

Comment: This is incorrect. Forward slashes only need to be escaped when they are also used as delimeters in regex literals and are not a part of a character class. In regexes, they do not mean anything special.