# HTML input validation pattern attribute - regex syntax differs from Javascript contrary to docs

Tags: javascript, regex, input

Can someone explain what in the docs I have missed that may account for the following inconsistency? Observed in both Firefox and Chrome.

The syntax of character classes for a regex in the HTML form input 'pattern' attribute appears to be subtly different from that of a regex in regular Javascript code. Specifically, when a hyphen appears in a character class standing for itself (not as a range separator) it must be backslash-escaped in a validation pattern, but this escaping doesn't appear to be necessary in a regex in JS code.

**Example**: Input should be two digits, separated by a hyphen or space.

In JS code this works as expected:

```
'56'.match(/\d[- ]\d/)  -- does not match
'5-6'.match(/\d[- ]\d/)  -- matches
```

However, if I use `'\d[- ]\d'` as a validation pattern attribute on an input element the browser ignores it, reporting that there is an invalid character in the class. It's necessary to write the pattern with the hyphen escaped: `'\d[\- ]\d'`

There is nothing I can find in MDN's docs on the input pattern attribute that might explain this discrepancy. Can anyone elucidate?

**EDIT** The comment below (which also closed this question) is correct but incomplete. What I had missed, and is crucial, and is NOT mentioned in the comment, is that an input element's pattern attribute implicitly adds the `v` flag to its validation regex. That flag tightens the escaping rules, as clarified in [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76285652/3832970)

Comment: [Already explained here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/76285652/3832970)