# Chrome gives error for regex ^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)$

Tags: regex, google-chrome

I'm not able to make this regex works on Chrome browser.

```
^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)$
```

This regex validates that the string:

- Does not start with a hyphen ("-").
- Contains only uppercase letters, lowercase letters, digits, and hyphens ("-").
- Has a length between 1 and 63 characters.
- Does not end with a hyphen ("-").

I'm using this regex in the pattern attribute of a input type text in my application.
Chrome gives me this error.

[image]

The regex works on online regex validators as https://regex101.com/.

I've already searched online but I'm note able to find the problem in this regex,

From ispector, this is the code of my input

```
<input pattern="^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9-]{1,63}(?<!-)$" type="text" name="third-level-domains" id="third-level-domains" autocomplete="true" class="text-gray-900 bg-white border border-borders sm:text-sm focus:ring-primary-500 focus:border-primary-500 block w-full dark:bg-gray-700 dark:border-gray-600 dark:placeholder-gray-400 dark:text-white dark:focus:ring-primary-500 dark:focus:border-primary-500 thirdLevelDomainsInput" placeholder="example">
```

I've already checked here [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285652/valid-with-the-regexp-u-flag-but-not-with-the-v-flag) but I wasn't able to understand how modify my regex to make it works

Comment: Correct. See the `/v` flag? Fix as `^(?!-)[A-Za-z0-9\-]{1,63}(?<!-)$`

Comment: It seems you concatenated the string with something non-related to the Regexp you're created, because error complains about the following part: `<!-)$/v`

While your original expression doesn't have `/v`

Comment: @VladimirPosvistelik I don't understand because I have not concatenation to the string... checking on google I've seen that /v is something that comes with the new chrome version..

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew thank you your regex solved my problem!!!

Comment: @JEricaM If it was not you (because it was not obvious to me initially), and you're using Regexp "as is" in an input pattern attribute... Then root of the problem is here: https://chromestatus.com/feature/5149507107422208, while `/v` flag explanation lives for example here: https://v8.dev/features/regexp-v-flag

Comment: ... and for those, who are wondering what happened in general. With `/v` flag (now default in Chrome) character `-` got different semantics. Now it means "exclude the following". So an original regexp had part `-]`, which means "exclude `]`". It broke regexp, so fix was in escaping of `-` character: `\-]`

Comment: Oh man, this will break a lot of regexes (and IMHO it's wrong syntax by google).

Comment: OK, we need more awareness. I published a shorts on this topic, https://www.youtube.com/shorts/vAFKdlzrq0g.