# Why does a regex using an unescaped dash `-` character not seem to work in a `pattern` attribute in HTML but it works when testing on regex101?

Tags: html, regex

```
<div class="formRow">
    <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
    <input name="custPhone" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" 
     pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$" > 
</div>
```

This comes from a textbook (albeit a few years old) and I don't know why the browser just accepts anything.

Can anyone see what might be preventing the regex from doing its job to get 7 or 10 digit phone numbers to be validated and other patterns to be rejected?

When I take just the expression and test at regex101.com, the expression seems to do its job there.

`^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s-]?\d{4}$`

On regex101.com 1234567   will match and 1234567890 will match and other patterns with fewer than 7, more than 10 and patterns with 8, and 9 digits will be rejected.

The textbook's other regex validation is fine.
It doesn't seem to be related to the browser as it fails with two different browsers.

Comment: This QA is currently being discussed on meta https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/427667/73226 (cc @AdrianMole)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

### Why is it invalid

The value provided to a `pattern` attribute is converted into a regular expression with the [`v` flag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/RegExp#flags) for [unicode sets](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicodeSets).

The [HTML standard](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#attr-input-pattern) defines that:

> The compiled pattern regular expression of an input element, if it exists, is a JavaScript RegExp object. It is determined as follows:
>
> 1. If the element does not have a `pattern` attribute specified, then return nothing. The element has no compiled pattern regular expression.
> 2. Let *pattern* be the value of the `pattern` attribute of the element.
> 3. Let *regexpCompletion* be RegExpCreate(*pattern*, "v").
> 4. If *regexpCompletion* is an abrupt completion, then return nothing. The element has no compiled pattern regular expression.
> 5. Let *anchoredPattern* be the string "^(?:", followed by *pattern*, followed by ")$".
> 6. Return ! RegExpCreate(*anchoredPattern*, "v").

In `v` (unicode sets) mode, [it is mandatory to escape a single dash inside a character class](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Regular_expressions/Character_class#v-mode_character_class) (among other values that are valid outside `v`) even if it is next to a bracket. Demo:

```js
const nonV = new RegExp(/[a-]/);

console.log('nonV match "a"', nonV.test("a"));
console.log('nonV match "-"', nonV.test("-"));
console.log('nonV match "b"', nonV.test("b"));

try {
  const v = new RegExp(/[a-]/, "v"); // throws an error

  console.log('v match "a"', v.test("a"));
  console.log('v match "-"', v.test("-"));
  console.log('v match "-"', v.test("b"));
  
} catch (error) {
  console.error("cannot use unescaped dash:", error.message)
}

const vEscaped = new RegExp(/[a\-]/, "v");

console.log('vEscaped match "a"', vEscaped.test("a"));
console.log('vEscaped match "-"', vEscaped.test("-"));
console.log('vEscaped match "b"', vEscaped.test("b"));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important }
```

#### When did it become invalid?

This was changed in April 2023 from the previous [`u` (unicode)](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp/unicode) flag to `v` (unicode sets), thus resulting in a breaking change for HTML that uses the `pattern` attribute with certain unescaped values. From [the GutHub Pull Request for this change to the HTML standard](https://github.com/whatwg/html/pull/7908), Mathias Bynens said:

> **[BREAKING CHANGE]** Some previously valid patterns are now errors, specifically those with a character class including either an unescaped [special character](https://arai-a.github.io/ecma262-compare/snapshot.html?pr=2418#prod-ClassSetSyntaxCharacter) `(` `)` `[` `]` `{` `}` `/` `-` `\` `|` or [a double punctuator](https://arai-a.github.io/ecma262-compare/snapshot.html?pr=2418#prod-ClassSetReservedDoublePunctuator):
>
> ```
> pattern="[(]"
> pattern="[)]"
> pattern="[[]"
> pattern="[{]"
> pattern="[}]"
> pattern="[/]"
> pattern="[-]"
> pattern="[|]"
> pattern="[&&]"
> pattern="[!!]"
> pattern="[##]"
> pattern="[$$]"
> pattern="[%%]"
> pattern="[**]"
> pattern="[++]"
> pattern="[,,]"
> pattern="[..]"
> pattern="[::]"
> pattern="[;;]"
> pattern="[<<]"
> pattern="[==]"
> pattern="[>>]"
> pattern="[??]"
> pattern="[@@]"
> pattern="[``]"
> pattern="[~~]"
> pattern="[_^^]"
> ```
>
> Throwing patterns result in `inputElement.validity.valid === true` for any input value, so the only compatibility risk is that some value/pattern combinations that would previously result in `inputElement.validity.valid === false` now result in `inputElement.validity.valid === true`.

The impact of if invalidating previously valid patterns was considered to be low and the trade off allows using more powerful patterns to be used. Examples from the PR:

> ```
> pattern="[\p{ASCII_Hex_Digit}--[Ff]]"
> pattern="\p{RGI_Emoji}"
> pattern="[_\q{a|bc|def}]"
> ```

### Fix

Therefore, the `-` in `[\s-]` needs to be escaped in HTML:

```css
:invalid {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
}
```

```html
<div class="formRow">
    <label for="phone">Phone number</label>
    <input name="custPhone" id="phone" type="tel" placeholder="(nnn) nnn-nnnn" 
     pattern="^\d{10}$|^(\(\d{3}\)\s*)?\d{3}[\s\-]?\d{4}$" > 
</div>
```

The same fix would need to be applied to any other pattern that is now invalid with `v` (unicode sets) mode.

For more information see [Valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285652/valid-with-the-regexp-u-flag-but-not-with-the-v-flag)