# why this bootstrap regex giving me error?

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-5

It appears that I'm encountering an issue while attempting to validate phone numbers within a form using a regex pattern. The regex in question is:

```
^\+?([0-9]{1,4})?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?([0-9]{7})$
```

However, when implementing this regex, an error arises indicating:

```
Pattern attribute value ^\+?([0-9]{1,4})?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?([0-9]{7})$ is not a valid regular expression: Uncaught SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^\+?([0-9]{1,4})?[-\. ]?(\d{3})[-\. ]?([0-9]{7})$/v: Invalid character in character class
```

Strangely, when I validate this regex on platforms like [text](https://regexr.com/) OR [text](https://pythex.org/),it functions correctly and successfully validates phone numbers.

Any way to fix this??

Comment: _"Invalid character in character class"_ - https://regex101.com/r/6M4il0/1 suggest, the `-` at the start of your character classes probably need to be escaped.

Comment: Conversely, `.` does **not** have to be escaped in a character class.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why is my regex valid with the RegExp u flag, but not with the v flag and does not work in HTML pattern attribute?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76285652/why-is-my-regex-valid-with-the-regexp-u-flag-but-not-with-the-v-flag-and-does-n)